# No implicit view avaliable from A => Ordered[A] while using default values

Tags: scala, view, binary-search-tree, implicit

I'm implementing simple BST in Scala (based on generics). I have implemented abstract class:

```
abstract class MyTree[A <% Ordered[A]]() .....
```

And the subclass Node

```
case class Node[A <% Ordered[A]](v: A, left: MyTree[A] = Leaf[A], right: MyTree[A] = Leaf[A]) extends MyTree[A] .....
```

There is also a Leaf case class which represents empty Leaf of my tree. I suppouse it's okey so I wont post it's code here.
The problem is I get an error:

> No implicit view available from A => Ordered[A].
>   case class Node[A <% Ordered[A]](v: A, left: MyTree[A] = Leaf[A], right: MyTree[A] = Leaf[A]) extends MyTree[A]

When I change <% to <: everything works fine, except the fact that I would like to use my BST with Int as a type (which is not Ordered). I also know that the source of the problem are probably default values (Leaf[A]) I assign to my left and right. How should I fix it? And why does this error occure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the actual code it's difficult to assess at which point your implicit function `A => Ordered[A]` is missing.

But I would in any case recommend to not use a conversion to `Ordered[A]` but rather an individual type class `Ordering[A]`. Using that, you don't need to actually convert the element type, but you have an instance that provides the ordering operation. I cannot think of a case where I would prefer `Ordered` over `Ordering`.

I would also advise against constructor parameters in abstract types (`MyTree` in your case). Better define an abstract member instead. For example:

```
sealed trait MyTree[-A] {
  def contains(x: A): Boolean
}

case class Leaf[A](v: A) extends MyTree[A] {
  def contains(x: A): Boolean = x == v
}

case object Empty extends MyTree[Any] {
  def contains(x: Any): Boolean = false
}

case class Node[A](v: A, left: MyTree[A], right: MyTree[A])
                  (implicit val ordering: Ordering[A])
  extends MyTree[A] {

  def contains(x: A): Boolean = x == v || {
    import Ordering.Implicits._   // nice operator syntax
    (if (x < v) left else right).contains(x)
  }
}

val t = Node(5, Node(3, Leaf(1), Empty), Leaf(8))
(0 to 9).map(t.contains) // F T F T F T F F T F
```

(Here the contra-variance `-A` in the `MyTree` type allows to define `Empty` as a single case object, but you can also stick to invariant `A`)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I changed Ordered into Ordering and everything works perfect.